# glReadPixels to ImageMagick

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, cocoa, opengl

I want to save OpenGL view as image with ImageMagick. I searched the internet and found some info about that. So I now know that I need to use glReadPixels. Thats OK, but how then make image from these readed pixels?

---

Now code looks like this:

```
char *buffer = (char*) calloc(viewHeight * viewWidth * 4, sizeof(char));
glReadPixels( 0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_BYTE, buffer );
Blob b( buffer, 4 * viewWidth * viewHeight );
Image saveimage(b);
saveimage.write("subimageGcrop.png");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read pixels using `glReadPixels`, you need to copy them to a [blob](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Blob.html) object. Then you can create [Image](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html) object, and write to a file.

Something like this :

```
    char *buffer; // needs to be big enough
    glReadPixels( 0, 0, width, length, GL_BGR, GL_BYTE, buffer );
    Blob b( buffer, 3 * width * length );
    Image i( b, 3 * width * length, 3 );
    i.write( "img.jpg" );
```

You  might need to adjust the parameters.

Comment: I don't know why but I get SIGABRT error when reading blob data

Comment: @JuliusPetraška Can you post the code (what have you tried) in your question?

Comment: @JuliusPetraška You passed GL_RGBA to glReadPixels, but your data size is 3*width*height. Adjust the size to 4*width*height. Also other parameters (passed to Blob's and Image's constructors). Also you allocated buffer of 3*width*height size - should be 4*width*height.

Comment: Changed, but still the same problem

Comment: @JuliusPetraška Update the question with your new code please

Comment: Updated, I just changed from 3 to 4. As you said. 

By the way, if I try to use   
`Image i( b, 4 * width * length, 4 );`  I get error:  `No matching constructor for initialization of 'Magick::Image'`

Comment: Yes, I load all images for openGL texturing with imagemagick and it works

Comment: Fixed. It had to look like this:

`char *buffer = (char*) calloc(imgWidth * imgHeight * 4, sizeof(char));
            glReadPixels(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
            Blob b(buffer, 4 * imgWidth * imgHeight);
            Image svimage(imgWidth, imgHeight, "RGB", CharPixel, buffer);`